# Computer Speed and Python Runtime

Tags: python, html, performance, list, processor

So I have a bit of an issue that I am wondering if you guys can help me with. So I am writing a program right now that pulls some strings from html pages and adds them to a list. I have 50 some pages I am pulling data from. When I run the program it takes between 45 and 55 seconds to gather the data. Not bad, but I need to be somewhere on the order of 15-20 seconds.

So here is my question: My computer has a 800MHz process (ya I know, its four years old) and I am about to get a new computer, will having a faster processor help with this? If so what speed of processor should I look for to get to my desired speed. Is this speed more related to processor speed or connection speed (my internet connection is definitely fast enough for this application)? Is it able to be speed up?

Thanks!

Addition:

Here is the code used.

This function creates the list of lists that stores the data

```
def makesobjlist(objs, length):
    sets = [objs]
    for obj in objs:
        objlist = [obj]
        for i in range(1,length+1):
            objlist.append(0)
        sets.append(objlist)
    return sets
```

The following function then updates the list of lists

```
def update(objslist):
    for i in range(1, len(objslist)):
        objlist = objslist[i]
        objlist.append(getdata(objlist[0]))
        del(objlist[1])
```

Comment: have you tried profiling your script to see which parts are taking the longest?

Comment: Yes, the 45-55 seconds I am referring to is just the function the adds the data to their respective lists. The other parts of the program are fast enough

Comment: Data lists and stuff in python are faster then you may think. I have a 600MHz cpu and only move on cython heavy math. The delay it is because network requests, but do a simple timit and see if that's true.

Comment: well, if it's just the string operations that are taking a long time, and the actual scraping of the data from the websites is not, then a new processor will definitely help. It may also be helpful to try and refactor your code, as depending on how you're doing the string ops there could be significant room for improvement

Comment: So what I currently have is urllib taking the page and downloading it. The data is seperated by ":" so I use the .split(":") function to break it up and then use the index of the list created by this to get the piece of data I want. Does that seem too slow so should I try sometime else?

Comment: We can't give you an informed answer based only on wild guesses and a vague description. It's very likely that your algorithm has the wrong kind of performance characteristics and could be rewritten to be much faster. But we won't know until you show us some of your code.

Comment: I/O bound tasks benefit from parallelization. Use multiple threads.

Comment: Edit to include your code, as it stands this question is too vague.

Comment: Sorry about that. I added the two function you should need into the original post. Thanks!

Comment: *@user3142330*, you are wonderful in that you have learned this much coding in a 800 MHZ PC. paste the complete program, and let me know where are the pages you are dealing with, I will run on mine and tell you how much time it takes. Then we can compare the measures and reasons

Comment: Please give the **complete** code that you are trying to speed up and reformulate your question not to speak about hardware, and try considering things like [trequests](https://github.com/1stvamp/trequests) and tornado to make your networking async.  Try also to fetch pages on localhost not to be network bound and give the results.

Comment: Yes, it's how you are getting the page data downloaded that is likely to be most relevant to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python supports threading, multiple processes and queues.

You may gain some speed by simply having multiple workers perform the job than a single worker that has to wait. Basically you divide the "work" up amongst multiple programs (workers) that process the tasks at hand. This is much faster than having to wait for one long process to finish.

Similar post here:

[Threading in python using queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13481276/threading-in-python-using-queue)

[Multiprocessing vs Threading Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044580/multiprocessing-vs-threading-python)

Comment: The issue was resolved by using multiple threads, got the runtime from 50 seconds to 0.01 seconds

Answer (score 0):

```
del(objlist[1])
```

If the `objlist` here can be long (more than a few dozens), then this line has bad complexity: it shifts all the end of the list.  You should refactor the code to not do that.  For example, you could arrange that the item to remove is the *last* item of the list instead of the item at index 1; `del objlist[-1]` is always a constant-time operation.