# AttributeError 'module' has no attribute 'Queue"

Tags: python

I am trying to import Queue and I keep getting the following

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "threading.py", line 2, in <module>
    import Queue
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/Queue.py", line 5, in <module>
    import threading as _threading
  File "/Users/zaq/threading.py", line 10, in <module>
    queue = Queue.Queue()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Queue'
```

I am using the code in the link [Threading in python using queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13481276/threading-in-python-using-queue)

Also, I can import and use Queue in the python interpreter.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Name of my script was threading.py... Changed it and everthing works fine. Rookie mistake.

Comment: Yeah I was about to add a comment suggesting you change the script name, strange that the error came from the `Queue.Queue()` line though, I would have expected it to fail the first time you tried to use the threading module.

Comment: I agree. I think that the Queue.py was trying to import the script that I called threading.py instead of the actual threading script. Weird shit!

Comment: Don't forget to accept your own answer so people will know this question is resolved.

Comment: What's actually going on here is a circular import—`Queue` tries to `import threading`, which imports your module. Then your module tries to `import Queue` and use `Queue.Queue()`… but `Queue` is still in the middle of built imported, so it has no `Queue` member yet.

Comment: The reason it imports your module instead of the stdlib module of the same name is that the current working directory (as either `''` or `'.'`) is always ahead of the stdlib directories in `sys.path`. The reason that importing your module is running its top-level code even though your module has already been loaded is that you ran your module as a script, so it was loaded as `__main__` rather than `threading`.

Comment: In other words, there's tons of fun stuff to learn about the import process if you trace through this. But I wouldn't recommend doing that, because the 2.x import process is a poorly-documented mess; wait until you upgrade to 3.3 (or… don't wait, just upgrade now), then learn the cleaned-up and nicely-documented [import system](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html) instead.

Comment: Just made the same but different mistake. Called my script queue.py !