# Passing updated args to multiple threads periodically in python

Tags: python, multithreading

I have three base stations, they have to work in parallel, and they will receive a list every 10 seconds which contain information about their cluster, and I want to run this code for about 10 minutes. So, every 10 seconds my three threads have to call the target method with new arguments, and this process should last long for 10 minutes. I don't know how to do this, but I came up with the below idea which seems to be not quite a good one! Thus I appreciate any help.

I have a list named *base_centroid_assign* that I want to pass each item of it to a distinct thread. The list content will be updated frequently (supposed for instance 10 seconds), I so wish to recall my previous threads and give the update items to them.

In the below code, the list contains three items which have multiple items in them (it's nested). I want to have three threads stop after executing the quite simple target function, and then recall the threads with update item; however, when I run the below code, I ended up with 30 threads! (the *run_time* variable is 10 and list's length is 3).

How can I implement idea as mentioned above?

```
run_time = 10

def cluster_status_broadcasting(info_base_cent_avr):
    print(threading.current_thread().name)
    info_base_cent_avr.sort(key=lambda item: item[2], reverse=True)


start = time.time()

while(run_time > 0):
    for item in base_centroid_assign:
        t = threading.Thread(target=cluster_status_broadcasting, args=(item,))
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()

    print('Entire job took:', time.time() - start)
    run_time -= 1
```

Comment: [Raymond Hettinger talk on concurrency](https://youtu.be/Bv25Dwe84g0)

Comment: @jpmc26 Thank you very much for this wonderful video!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stackoverflow.

Problems with thread synchronisation can be so tricky to handle that Python already has some very useful libraries specifically to handle such tasks. The primary such library is `queue.Queue` in Python 3. The idea is to have a queue for each "worker" thread. The main thread collect and `put` new data onto a queue, and have the subsidiary threads `get` the data from that queue.

When you call a `Queue`'s `get` method its normal action is to block the thread until something is available, but presumably you want the threads to continue working on the current inputs until new ones are available, in which case it would make more sense to poll the queue and continue with the current data if there is nothing from the main thread.

I outline such an approach in my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54942503/cant-read-write-to-files-using-multithreading-in-python/54943940#54943940), though in that case the worker threads are actually sending return values back on another queue.

The structure of your worker threads' `run` method would then need to be something like the following pseudo-code:

```
def run(self):
    request_data = self.inq.get()  # Wait for first item
    while True:
        process_with(request_data)
        try:
            request_data = self.inq.get(block=False)
        except queue.Empty:
            continue
```

You might like to add logic to terminate the thread cleanly when a sentinel value such as `None` is received.

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive answer, I've searched and found out that I have to utilize queue too in order to handle such tasks; however, one of my colleagues said that you wouldn't achieve a palpable performance in python multithreading. I will upload the final code. For now, I will mark your answer as the correct one.

Comment: When multi-threading much depends on the nature of the problem. I had good results updating an email billing program to use 200 threads and avoid slow-down due to DNS delays and the like. YMMV.\

Comment: @Squishy33 Multithreading helps with IO bound processes (things that have to wait for network responses, disk reads, anything where the processing happens on a device other than the CPU). Multithreading is detrimental when the process is CPU bound, since Python only allows one thread to run at a time in a single process (controlled by the Global Interpret Lock, or GIL). Your colleague is either not very well informed or was concerned about a CPU bound process. (You may have already realized this watching the video I linked, but leaving the info if anyone else reads this in the future.)